# How do I unload and reload an assembly generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic-assemblies

I'm working on a utility that will allow you to compile a piece of code while running. I'd like to put that code in a temporary assembly and load it.

```
var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters {
  GenerateInMemory = true,
  OutputAssembly = "SomeName"
};
... // add assembly references
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, mySourceCode);
var payload = Activator.CreateInstance(results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First());
```

Later, after the user makes a change to the code, I'd like to create a new temporary assembly with the changes. However, it seems like the old version is sticking around and confusing the rest of my code. How do I unload the original temporary assembly?

Comment: follow the link, basically you can't unload an assembly, but you can unload an appdomain